# Export a html page to pdf with everything that's written on it, after submit button

Tags: php

I need to export html page to pdf file with everything that's written in it, after I press submit button. It will open new page, with info, and I need for script to automatically make .pdf file (already uploaded to webserver), and get the link from file. Could you give me some easy example (if available, without any plugins, or other features that I must download, I would prefer clean PHP).

Comment: There's a number of libraries that can do this, but if you're restricting yourself to no "plugins, or other features that I must download" then you've got a lot of code writing ahead of you. Either loosen your restriction and look at mPDF or tcPDF or domPDF, or good luck!

Comment: As @Mark Baker said, it is not good idea to re-invent wheel.

Comment: Okay well, basically I'm now setting up mPDF, but I can't find a feature, to just pdf current active page html source as pdf, could you please help me with that?

Comment: You spool the html markup for your page to mPDF, and save that to the browser rather than spooling the html markup directly to the browser

Comment: could you please write answer and includ example? I will accept you. I exactly, didn't understand about spool, so please includ example in answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just try this

HTML to PDF with PHP

Using open-source HTML2FPDF project

This solution uses HTML2PDF project (sourceforge.net/projects/html2fpdf/). It simply gets a HTML text and generates a PDF file. This project is based upon FPDF script (www.fpdf.org), which is pure PHP, not using the PDFlib or other third party library. Download [HTML2PDF][1], add it to your projects and you can start coding.
Code example

```
    require("html2fpdf.php");
    $htmlFile = "your link"; 
    $buffer = file_get_contents($htmlFile); 
    $pdf = new HTML2FPDF('P', 'mm', 'Letter'); 
    $pdf->AddPage(); 
    $pdf->WriteHTML($buffer); 
    $pdf->Output('test.pdf', 'F');
```